# IK bone arrange for kid riding toy

Tags: rigging

Hello Blender artists,

i wonder what could be the right IK bone arrange for this toy mechanism?
the motion loop is more like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhKRtBNinEM
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just use a simple arm IK rig. The "hand" (IK target) stays in place while the "shoulder" rotates in a circle.

[image: example animation]

The pole target is needed to prevent a "180° flip". Make sure the bone rolls are correct (check the bone axes), that the deform option is disabled for the helper bones and the bone hierarchy is correct so you can move the whole rig properly. The yellow bone has the IK constraint.

[image: constraint settings]

[image]